# How to load a node based on its title?

Tags: nodes

I only know the title of a node, and I want to load the node using `node_load()`.

How do I do that?

Comment: If its a normal Page you should get NID in `arg(1)` it will be node/X for all pages. and `node_load()` works on only NID

Comment: my url is  projects/{username}/{node title}, that is why I use arg(2)

Comment: in drupal 7 you can't use node_load() to get node by it's title, just by nid

Comment: Are your titles unique?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a node by a field value?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228548/how-to-load-a-node-by-a-field-value)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Drupal 6, you can use the following code.

```
$node = node_load(array('title' => 'node title'));
```

If you know the node's type as well, then you can use the following code.

```
$node = node_load(array('title' => 'node title', 'type' => 'page'));
```

[node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/6) always returns a single node. That is because the function doesn't loop over the database query result resource returned from [db_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.pgsql.inc/function/db_query/6).

```
  if ($revision) {
    array_unshift($arguments, $revision);
    $node = db_fetch_object(db_query('SELECT ' . $fields . ' FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {users} u ON u.uid = n.uid INNER JOIN {node_revisions} r ON r.nid = n.nid AND r.vid = %d WHERE ' . $cond, $arguments));
  }
  else {
    $node = db_fetch_object(db_query('SELECT ' . $fields . ' FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {users} u ON u.uid = n.uid INNER JOIN {node_revisions} r ON r.vid = n.vid WHERE ' . $cond, $arguments));
  }
```

Comment: @sokratis Keep in mind that titles don't have to be unique and can be changed at any time. If you can switch to referencing by node id, that would be safer.

Comment: Drupal is not a fan of CamelCase.

Comment: This example also just plain won't work in D7. [`node_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/7).  Have edited question tag to reflect this.

Comment: D7 version (albeit using the deprecated `$conditions` parameter): `$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('title' => 'node title'));`

Answer (score 50):

In Drupal 7, the parameters for `node_load()` has been changed. To get the nodes that match some conditions, you should use the [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) class.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();


 $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('type', 'your_node_type')
  ->propertyCondition('title', 'your node title')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->range(0,1)
  ->execute();

  if (!empty($entities['node'])) {
    $node = node_load(array_shift(array_keys($entities['node'])));
  }
```

Comment: node_load(array('title' => 'node title', 'type' => 'page')) - this will obsolete soon, so this answer is correct.

Comment: This is so long in order to load a single node;/

Answer (score 14):

#### Drupal 7

Here is a simpler way (as already suggested by [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5955/how-to-load-a-node-based-on-its-title/167169#comment32303_5960) and at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16591333/55075)):

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple(NULL, array("title" => "Foo Bar"));
$node = current($nodes);
```

and much easier to remember than using [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) class.

See also: [Programmatically getting nodes by title in Drupal 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8369713/55075) at SO

Comment: nice approach, unfortunalty intented to die, as exposed in  [https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7.x]   (function node_load_multiple)  `@todo Remove $conditions in Drupal 8.`

Comment: This code is not compatible with Drupal 8, where the second argument of `node_load_multiple()` is a Boolean value telling Drupal to reset the internal cache used for the loaded entities.

Comment: @augusto That isn't a reason sufficient not to use the code shown here, though. Even using the `EntityFieldQuery` class would require changes to port the code to Drupal 8.

Answer (score 11):

In Drupal 7, you can use code similar to the following one.

```
$result = db_query("SELECT n.nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.title = :title AND n.type = :type", array(":title"=> $title, ":type"=> $type));  
$nid = $result->fetchField();
```

Comment: Doesn't title stored in the node_revision table?

Answer (score 11):

In Drupal 8, run this:

```
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadByProperties(['title' => $title]);
foreach ( $nodes as $node ) {
  $node->doSomething(...);
}
```

`$node` will be a fully instantiated node object.

Answer (score 6):

**Also in Drupal 8**

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
->condition('title', 'YourNodeTitle')
->sort('nid', 'DESC')
->execute();
```

and next:

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(HEREYOUNODEID);
```

Dont forget you need

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
```