# in drupal 7, how to get node id from node title?

Tags: nodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to load a node based on its title?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5955/how-to-load-a-node-based-on-its-title)

I know the node title, and I want to get node id from the node title, I tried 2 ways but not working properly

```
// get node title from the url
$title = arg(2); 

$node = node_load(array('title' => $title));    
$nid = $node->nid;

print $nid;
```

errors are saying that Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() , Trying to get property of non-object

2

```
 $items = entity_load('node', FALSE, array(
            'type' => 'article',
            'title' => arg(2),
    ));
```

but then what I should do ?