# Query and load entity by Entity Type Manager

Tags: 8, entities

Currently I am firstly "searching" for an taxonomy term entity with the Entity Query in Drupal 8:

```
$termIds = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
  ->condition('field_code', $code)
  ->condition('vid', 'computer')
  ->execute();
```

And then I am loading the taxonomy term entity:

```
      $termId = current($termIds);
      $term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
        ->load($termId);
```

Is there a way to do it in 1 step, instead of these two?

Answer (score 17):

You can do this in one step by using [loadByProperties()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageInterface.php/function/EntityStorageInterface%3A%3AloadByProperties/8.4.x):

```
$term = current(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
  ->loadByProperties(['field_code' => $code, 'vid' => 'computer'])
);
```

This method is a shortcut for basic entity queries like you have here and also includes the step for loading the entities.

Comment: Nice, haven’t sent that one before

Comment: I have tried it with an node title and this does not work:


current(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')
      ->loadByProperties(
        [
          'title' => $title,
          'type' => 'authority'
        ]
      )
    );

Comment: Your code is OK. I've put in a title and type from a node I have on my site and it worked!

Comment: I have tested it again. And again it does not work. I have wrote a method to shorten this up:   private function loadNodeByProperties(array $conditions) {
    $query = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getQuery();
    foreach ($conditions as $field => $value) {
      $query->condition($field, $value);
    }

    return Node::load(current($query->execute()));
  }

Comment: yes, this should work too, but loadByProperties() does the same: `foreach ($values as $name => $value) { $entity_query->condition($name, (array) $value, 'IN'); }`, only using 'IN' so that you could provide an array with multiple values.